# Problem with my small dictionary quiz. can someone explain this error please

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
d = {'Red': 1, 'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3} 
for color_key, value in d.items():
    userinput == (input(color_key))
    if userinput == (d[color_key]):
       print("correct")
    else: 
        print("wrong")
```

Hi everyone, i am trying to simulate a quiz with this dictionary. I want to iterate through the dictionary and prompt the user for the questions (which is the key) (i.e what is the number for the colour: color_key). I then want the user to put the value for the key that corresponds to the right colour.

I am getting this error: 
userinput == input(color_key)

NameError: name 'userinput' is not defined

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Your error is caused by doube equal sign (==) instead of single = in line 3. (brackets not needed as well). But even after that correction, I dont believe your algorithm is actually doing its purpose. Can you please try to rephrase task of game you are making?

Comment: No worries, I was kinda in a rush when posting this. Basically I wanted to use a dictionary which will store both my questions and answers together. So I want to iterate though the dictionary: d. Let’s suppose the keys were questions, how do I use the keys as questions and then values as answers. I’m not sure how to approach the logic. So my question is, how should I approach the logic so that my code will prompt the user with a question (which will be the key In the dictionary) and then they must enter the correct answer (value of the key) I.e Red? (User inputs 1)

Comment: I've edited my response according to newest info you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Based on assumptions that you want to make kind of "memory" game with colors and integers, code proposal for your game would be something like this:

```
import random
d = {'Red': 1, 'Green': 2, 'Blue': 3} 
while 1==1:
    rand1 = random.choice(list(d))
    user_input = input("Please guess the code of "+rand1+" color:\n")
    try:
        int(user_input)
        if(int(user_input) == d[rand1]):
            print("Color code is correct!")
        else:
            print("Color code is incorrect!")
    except ValueError:
        if(user_input.lower() == "quit"):
            print("Program will terminate now")
        else:
            print("Invalid input provided.")
```

Take in consideration few things important for these kind of exercises:

- Despite python is not strictly typizied language, you have to take
  care of exceptions in the user input
- "While 1==1" generates something
  called "dead loop". Make sure you always have exit condition for this
  one - In our case out here, that is keyword "quit" on the input.
- In case of keyword "quit" on the input, it has to be validated for both
  upper and lowercase

---

EDIT:
According to your newest update, I am providing you the example of simple 3-operations based game:

```
import random

def detect_string_operation(elem1, elem2, operator):
    result = ""
    if(operator == "+"):
        result = str(elem1 + elem2)
    elif(operator == "-"):
        result = str(elem1 - elem2)
    elif(operator == "*"):
        result = str(elem1 * elem2)
    elif(operator == "/"):
        result = str(elem1/elem2)
    return result

operators_list = ["+", "-", "*"]
while 1==1:
    elem1 = random.randint(0, 10)
    elem2 = random.randint(0, 10)
    operator_index = random.randint(0, len(operators_list)-1)
    result_operation = detect_string_operation(elem1, elem2, operators_list[operator_index])
    user_input = input("Please calculate following: "+str(elem1)+str(operators_list[operator_index])+str(elem2)+"=")
    try:
        int(user_input)
        if(user_input == result_operation):
            print("Result is correct!")
        else:
            print("Result is incorrect!")
    except ValueError:
        if(user_input.lower() == "quit"):
            print("Program will terminate now")
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input provided.")
```

Note that I didn't implement division for a reason: for division totally random choice of values is not an option, since we need an integer as a result of division. Algorithm for generating divisor and divider pair is quite simple to be implemented in iterative way, but it is out of scope of your initial question.

Comment: Hi, really appreciate the response. Yes does seem like I want to create a memory game, however I actually want to create a math quiz. I.e d = {‘8+3’ : 10, .....} how would you approach something like this?

Comment: I just used this example because it might be easier to understand

Comment: Hey man, this is awesome! the only thing is, part of my specification is to use a dictionary in my assignment from my boss. Is there a way i can do this? Or better put, is it possible to have a dictionary which can hold the questions asked, correct answer, and users attempt too?

Comment: Then simply generate element 1 and element 2 from random dict index selection, and not with randint, and that's about it :) Here you are the example: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/sgzBjbvT9k/